# MS Dynamics-CRM How can I find GUID of the existing view by "Display Name" using JS?

Tags: dynamics-crm, lookup, fetchxml, defaultview

I have category 1, category 2, and category 3. Cat1 is parent of cat2. Cat2 is parent of cat3. View for every category filtered by parent.

**Problem:** category 3 doesn't get filtered if cat2 is not specified when cat1 selected.

**Need:** in addition to existing functionality I need to be able to filter by grandparent as well.

**My solution** : 
What I'm doing now -> I am able to create a custom view. When on form load or on change of cat1 i'm running a script which sets a default custom view. But in this scenario - i need to change view back when category 2 is specified. (Because user can choose category 1 -> then category 2 and then 3).
To set a default view I need to provide GUID of desired view.

**Question1:** is it the way to do it?

**Question2:** How can I find GUID of the existing view by "Display Name" using JS?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know why I couldn't think of it before, but all what I need to do is to specify a second condition in the same query. "SELECT this FROM this WHERE cat1=1 and cat2=2